# address.transfer executes but doesn't make the transfer

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript

I'm using Metamask and web3.js to connect with a donation smart contract. Following is my JavaScript function:

```
function withdraw(){
    const contractInstance = connectToContract();

    var withdrawAmount = parseInt(document.getElementById('withdraw-amount').value);
    var goalID = 0;
    var donationEvent = contractInstance.DonationAction();

    contractInstance.withdraw.sendTransaction(goalID, web3.toWei(withdrawAmount, 'ether'), {

    }, function(err, wei) {
        if (err)
          console.log(err); 
    });

    donationEvent.watch(function(error, result){
        if (!error) {
            if (result.args.action == 'unverified'){
                window.alert('The goal is still ' + result.args.action);
            } else if (result.args.action == 'insufficient balance') {
                window.alert('There is ' + result.args.action + ' in the account. Send a value less than ' + result.args.amount);
            } else if (result.args.action == 'donated') {
                window.confirm('You have successfully ' + result.args.action + ' ' + result.args.amount);
            }
        } else {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Following is my contract code:

```
struct Goal {
        address payable charityAddress;
        string status;
        uint amountNeeded;
        uint amountRaised;
        uint amountWithdrawn;
        uint balance;
        string proof;
        address verifier;
    }

function withdraw(uint _goalID, uint _amount) payable public {
        if (bytes(goals[_goalID].status).length != bytes("verified").length) {
            emit DonationAction(msg.sender, _amount, "unverified");
            return;
        } else if ((_amount * 1000000000000000000) > goals[_goalID].balance) {
            emit DonationAction(msg.sender, _amount, "insufficient balance");
            return;
        }

        goals[_goalID].balance = goals[_goalID].balance - _amount;

        goals[_goalID].charityAddress.transfer(address(this).balance);
        goals[_goalID].amountWithdrawn = goals[_goalID].amountWithdrawn + _amount;

        emit DonationAction(msg.sender, address(this).balance, "withdrawn");
    }
```

The transaction executes without any error but the ether doesn't get transferred to the Metamask account. The contract balance doesn't reduce either. And none of the events are emitted.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The first thing to check is whether one of the two conditional blocks is returning without doing anything, by design. Consider rewriting as `require` and reverting if the requests are unacceptable. Also, the `transfer` should be the last statement for reentrance defense.

Comment: @RobHitchens You were right! I was inputting the amount in wei and multiplying it again (thinking it was input in Ether). Thank you so much!!